# Why is it right to say you die "from" an illness instead "of" an illness?

Tags: prepositions

I just found this sentence in an article in [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v525/n7567/full/525030a.html):

> Lovelace died in great pain at 36, **from** uterine cancer.

And I'm confused about the use of "from". I know "from" is used to express physical origin (e.g., He moved *from* Paris), but in this case the preposition is used to state the cause of something (the death of somebody). Is this use valid?

Comment: This has already been discussed in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126187/die-from-cancer-vs-die-of-cancer)

Comment: You can say to die of / from - See the entry for *die* in the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/die_1?q=die)

Comment: I would never say *She died from cancer*. I speak American English and agree with [this answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/126188/153649).