# Do you die "from" or die "of" cancer? Which preposition do you use?

Tags: prepositions

Do you die "from" or die "of" cancer? Which preposition do you use?

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die+from%2Cdie+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) indicates that "die of" is more common, with the observation *Search for "die from" yielded only one result*.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find a duplicate target on ELL. This question has been asked on ELU, but I hope we will get model answers under this post for future duplicates.

Comment: I agree "die of" is much more common. However, [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/die_1?q=die): **die of/from something** *to die of/from cancer* (= cancer is the cause of death)

Comment: [Why is it right to say you die “from” an illness instead “of” an illness?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/67311/9161) and [About Die(d) of and die(d) from](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/168171/9161) would be duplicates if they had answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [died from/ died of.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214701/died-from-died-of) Broadly speaking people can *Die **of** diseases and old age and bad habits*, or *Die **from** wounds and injuries*, or *Die **in** an accident*.

Comment: [*Here's*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+died+of+cancer%2Cwho+died+from+cancer%2Cwho+died+with+cancer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20died%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20died%20from%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20died%20with%20cancer%3B%2Cc0) the relevant usage chart.